Why is my OpenMP based Code not getting any speedup?
I am trying to fill in "valid points" into a vector of vectors and I do it with the use of local vector of vector which I then merge. I also write the time measuring strategy for completeness:
const char* pcData = pkt.data().c_str(); // big string
int numChannels = 128;
int numThreads = 1;

std::vector<std::vector<int>> rowGlobalIds(numChannels, std::vector<int>());
for(auto& v: rowGlobalIds){
  v.reserve(3000);
}

#pragma omp parallel num_threads(numThreads)
{
  omp_set_nested(1);
  double wtime = omp_get_wtime();
  int thread_num = omp_get_thread_num();
  int localItNumber = 0;
  int localValidNumber = 0;
  // Create local vector, to be merged below
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> thIds(numChannels, std::vector<int>());
  for(auto& v: thIds){
    v.reserve(1500);
  }
  #pragma omp for nowait schedule(static)
  for(int i=0; i < pointCount; ++i){
    int16_t val1 = copyFromBuffer(pcData, i, 1);
    if(val1 > threshold){
      uint16_t row = copyFromBuffer(pcData, i, 2);
      thIds[row].push_back(i);
      localValidNumber++;
    }
    localItNumber++;
  }
  wtime = omp_get_wtime() - wtime;
  printf( "Time taken by thread %d is %f ms with %d iterations and %d valid points\n", thread_num, wtime*1000, itcounts[thread_num], validPoints[thread_num] );
  
  // Merging local vectors of vectors. This must be in order th 0 then 1
  #pragma omp for schedule(static) ordered
  for(int th = 0; th < omp_get_num_threads(); ++th) {
    for(int i = 0; i < numChannels; ++i){
      #pragma omp ordered
      rowGlobalIds[i].insert(rowGlobalIds[i].end(), thIds[i].begin(), thIds[i].end());
    }
  }

  omp_set_nested(0);
}

If pData contains e.g. around 600,000 positions and I do two test runs I get:
For numThreads = 1:

Thread 0:

Iterations 634,060
Valid Points 214,742
Runtime 33.936843 ms



For numThreads = 2:

Thread 0:

Iterations 317,644
Valid Points 112,428
Runtime 34.031533 ms


Thread 1:

Iterations 317,644
Valid Points 102,304
Runtime 26.162064 ms



Why is the time anyhow almost the same in the end if in principle one is reading from buffer half of the time?
I have not tried anything more than measuring the performance with the code above.

There is some false sharing on validPoints accesses causing a serialisation of the cache line accesses.  On top of that, maybe your code is memory bound or bound by the large amount of possible allocation done by the rather inefficient data structure std::vector<std::vector<int>>. Besides, I do not expect the ordered part to be faster in parallel (due ro the ordering and also because it should be memory bound anyway. I think we cannot help much more without profiling information or a minimal reproducible example. Especially since the speed of the code is data dependent.

Jérôme Richard thanks for your answer. I corrected the false sharing above. The ordered part is for sure not helping but on the other hand I am measuring only the runtime on the first loop. If you mean there might be a dependency of the 1st loop on the 2nd one then I could recheck. Also the std::vector<std::vector<int>> are being pushed back to, i.e. keep reallocating memory if needed, could this also be a problem? Should I use as local containers e.g. a fixed size array and write by index?

When doing parallel operations like this, it is better to preallocate the arrays. If you do not know the size, then a 2 step operations can sometimes be faster. As for the second loop, I advise you to remove the parallel pragma since not only it should not be faster but I expect this to cause a race condition (i.e. undefined behaviour which often impact performance, may cause data corruption and also crashes). A critical section should be used instead. Besides, preallocating rowGlobalIds should impact performance and you can easily compute its size based on thIds.

I suspect that the memory access pattern to thIds is quite random in the 1st loop, which tends to make this loop memory bound (all the more than it doesn't perform a lot of calculations otherwise).


Your localValidNumber has a race condition: declare a reduction on it. 2. Your ordered loop can be done much more elegantly in C++ by overloading the + operator on the object you're merging. 3. How big is your point count? Maybe you don't have enough work to offset thread creation.


Very important: are you sure that there are no clashes on val2? If two threads try to push back on the same val2 value, your results will be total nonsense.

To Jérôme Richard: I updated the code by reserving memory a priori for the global (128x3000) and local (128x1500 for 2 threads) containers, I actually did not see much change in the numbers, I keep using push_back and insert, but this time on preallocated containers. To Victor Eijkhout I am working with around 600 000 points being read from memory and after filtering with the threshold as you can see now I expect a maximum size of 128x3000 (around 390 000). I would not expect thread creation to take more than a couple of ms but I am not sure.

To PierU: val2 is surely bounded between 0 and 127 (thIds is of size 128 x 1500). What do you mean with random access?

Victor Eijkhout: My understanding is that one creates a parallel region with #pragma omp parallel num_threads(numThreads), then 2 threads are spawned and each has a local copy of what happens inside (e.g. its own thIds, localValidNumber localItNumber and so on). Each fills in its own thIds. After the first for loop the second one waits for thread 0 and appends its thIds to rowGlobalIds, after which thread 1 does the same. From this I would not expect clashes but let me know if you see it differently.

"random access" in contrast to "sequential access". But if you have only 128 channels it's maybe not too bad... Anyway this loop has apparently a low "arithmetic intensity", so not the best candidate for parallelization.

Thank you very much for your help everyone! I really tried making my post clean and enriching it with all your ideas. The score of -2 still means someone does not like it... I guess some people just want to watch the world burn. As I have not been able to bring the runtimes down anymore I guess I will keep this question open for anyone joining.

Thank you I edited the code. Yes the code is part of a more complex code base itself but I am trying to simplify it here. Next time I will try to write it and compile it separately. Another test I made was sending a smaller amount of data (i.e. instead of 600 000 points directly sent 200 000) from the source and the time is also not changing a lot. Points maybe in the direction of a memory bound problem, given that the pcData pointer itself is from a std::string it may not be in the stack but somewhere else farther away
